# jBPM 7.11: How to fix "unable to parse xml" exception?

Tags: jbpm

I'm using jBPM 7.11. I have a business process that compiles in the Eclipse BPMN2 Diagram Editor. Its associated XML content is well formed and valid when parsed in Eclipse or in any other XML parser. However, doing a maven build raises the following exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.9.0.Final:build (default-build) on project shopping-cart: Execution default-build of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.9.0.Final:build failed: Unable to get KieModule, Errors Existed: Error Messages:
[ERROR] Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=home/nicolas/workspace/samples-parent/eap-parent/bpm-parent/shopping-cart/src/main/resources/fr/simplex_software/red_hat/eap/bpm/shopping_cart/shopping-cart.bpmn, line=-1, column=0
[ERROR]    text=unable to parse xml : Exception class java.lang.NullPointerException : null]
[ERROR] ---
[ERROR] Warning Messages:
[ERROR] ---
[ERROR] Info Messages:
```

What might be the issue here and how could I fix it ?
Many thanks in advance.
Nicolas

Comment: I'm updating the post. Trying to import the related business process into BusinessCentral (Red Hat Process Automation Manager 7.1) I get more information on the exception, but still unable to figure out what happens.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I can't paste the stack trace here because only a few characters are allowed. Very weird.
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
 at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
 at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
 ...

Comment: at org.kie.workbench.common.stunner.bpmn.backend.converters.tostunner.properties.AssignmentsInfos.outAssociationDeclarations(AssignmentsInfos.java:139)
 at org.kie.workbench.common.stunner.bpmn.backend.converters.tostunner.properties.AssignmentsInfos.parsed(AssignmentsInfos.java:90)
 at org.kie.workbench.common.stunner.bpmn.backend.converters.tostunner.properties.AssignmentsInfos.of(AssignmentsInfos.java:69)
 at org.kie.workbench.common.stunner.bpmn.backend.converters.tostunner.properties.UserTaskPropertyReader.getAssignmentsInfo(UserTaskPropertyReader.java:71)

Answer (score 0):

you likely have a semi colon accidently put in your when predicates